# error when trying to upload code to esp8266

Tags: esp8266

Sketch uses 344,292 bytes (32%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1,044,464 bytes.
Global variables use 32,276 bytes (39%) of dynamic memory, leaving 49,644 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81,920 bytes.
error: Failed to open COM1
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

---

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: when I am trying to upload code to nodeMCU board I am getting this error message--   Sketch uses 344,292 bytes (32%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1,044,464 bytes. Global variables use 32,276 bytes (39%) of dynamic memory, leaving 49,644 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81,920 bytes. error: Failed to open COM1 error: espcomm_open failed error: espcomm_upload_mem failed

Comment: I am sending error message coz I want solution for that.. what do u expect to send ??????????????????????????????

Answer (score 0):

Try holding down the flash button when uploading the code to the board.

The ESP8266 and the ESP32 need certain buttons held down to open the COM port to upload code.